# Are pipeline variables available in PowerShell task in Azure DevOps?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, environment-variables

I have this PowerShell script, that reads some environment variables and outputs them:

```
Write-Host "name: $(tenantName) version: $(versionRelease) url: $(urlApplication)"
```

Those variables are defined as pipeline variables and also in variable groups in an Azure DevOps release pipeline.

When run inside a [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) defined as **Inline**, this script works as expected. However, the same exact script won't work when the PowerShell task is configured with a **File Path**. In this case, the `tenantName` env variable is not found:

```
tenantName : The term 'tenantName' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Is there any way to make the environment variables available to a "File" script as they are to an "Inline" one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to fix it, partially thanks to @Cbsch's answer. Indeed, the syntax of my PowerShell script was not correct, but changing `$(tenantName)` to `$tenantName` didn't fix the problem, since the `$tenantName` didn't exist. I had to read it from the environment variables, with the `$env:<variableName>` syntax.

The fixed script:

```
Write-Host "name: $env:tenantName version: $env:versionRelease url: $env:urlApplication"
```

Answer (score 4):

I can't answer to the Azure part of it, but your code is not valid for what you are trying. You need to include the `$` inside the `$()` blocks.

As it is now, Powershell is trying to call a function named `tenantName`, or find an application named `tenantName.exe` to call.

This will work:

```bsh
Write-Host "name: $($tenantName) version: $($versionRelease) url: $($urlApplication)"
```

Or even better:

```bsh
Write-Host "name: $tenantName version: $versionRelease url: $urlApplication"
```

The `$()` syntax is used if you need to put some actual code into the string, like referencing a property, like `Write-Host "Hello $($user.name)!"`